# Using POST data after validating using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, registration

I have a signup form where I'm validating user input. Here's my controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Register extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('Users_model');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $data['page_title'] = 'Register';
        $this->load->view('header', $data);

        // Set form validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[16]|xss_clean|callback_username_check');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[64]|valid_email|callback_email_check');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span class="error">', '</span>');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('register', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            // Add the user to the database
            $this->Users_model->add_user();
            $this->load->view('register_success', $data);
        }

        $this->load->view('footer', $data);
    }

    /* Functions to check username and email */
}

/* End of file register.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/register.php */
```

The problem is with this line: `$this->Users_model->add_user();`. I want to pass the username, email and password to my Users model to add the user to my database, but I'm not sure how I can get the POST data into that method. Normally I'd use `$_POST['username']` etc but CodeIgniter has run some functions on the input values (`trim()`, `xss_clean` etc). How can I get these values and pass them into my `add_user()` method?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [CodeIgniter input class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) allows you to get the POST data after it has been filtered by the form validation library.  In your controller you would do the following:

```
$username = $this->input->post('username');
$email = $this->input->post('email');
$password = $this->input->post('password');
```

Comment: Thought it'd be this but wasn't sure so thought I'd ask. Thank you. :)

Comment: SO doesn't allow me to accept an answer right away, apparently I can in 3 minutes. :)

Answer (score 1):

even easier, create an array and send the array to the model

Answer (score 0):

You can use the input class as well as the helper function `set_value('email')`