# CodeIgniter Get Value From Form Field

Tags: php, codeigniter

I know this is a stupid question but after messing around, I am confused what is the right way of doing.

Below are my code :

View registration_form.php :

```
$input_data = array(
    'name'      => 'user_name',
    'id'        => 'user_name',
    'value'     => set_value('user_name'),
    'maxlength' => MAX_CHARS_4_USERNAME
);
```

Controller register.php:

```
$this->load->model('user_model');
$this->user_model->create_user( 'customer', array() );
```

Form Validation Config :

```
$config['customer_creation_rules'] = array(
    array(
        'field' => 'user_name',
        'label' => 'USERNAME',
        'rules' => 'trim|required|alpha|strtolower'
    )
);
```

Model user_model.php :

```
public function create_user( $role, $insert_array = array() )
    {
        // The form validation class doesn't allow for multiple config files, so we do it the old fashion way
        $this->config->load( 'form_validation/administration/create_user/create_' . $role, TRUE );
        $this->validation_rules = config_item( $role . '_creation_rules' );


        $form_username = $this->config->item($role . '_creation_rules', 'field');


        echo $form_username;
    }
```

What I want to do right now is to check the username that the user input and auto add a number to the input username before inserting into database.

Initially I thought of getting the inputted username from the Form Validation, after messing around, I can't get the value no matter what I have tried.

Am I doing it wrongly? Do I just get from $_POST instead?

Hope you guys can help me out on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this has what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641907/using-post-data-after-validating-using-codeigniter

Comment: Thanks dgig! Been finding it for very long and couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: yep, good luck! Sometimes it is hard to ind things, I try and help. some d'heads just downvote.

Comment: Hi dgig! I just happened to tried entering something that I forgot to test. I have this for my form : 'rules' => 'trim|required|alpha|strtolower' 
In that post you have given me, the contributor mentioned : "The CodeIgniter input class allows you to get the POST data after it has been filtered by the form validation library." But when I use $this->input->post(); command, somehow the data that I got is the raw value data. Is it that strtolower is not considered as form validation for CodeIgniter?

Comment: This shows the full list (waaaay at the bottom): http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html. I don't see that one there, but it says you can use any PHP function that requires only one parameter so that should work, but you'll have to look deeper into the docs to figure out why it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

This shows the full list (waaaay at the bottom): http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

I don't see that one there, but it says you can use any PHP function that requires only one parameter so that should work, but you'll have to look deeper into the docs to figure out why it isn't.

I don't think you can set rules for a form, you have to set them per variable, as the docs show:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|is_unique[users.username]');
```

Comment: I have looked through that document and I am still confused. Sorry, I am still new to CI, can't really get what is going on. If I don't do anything extra, meaning if I do not get the username and do some extra stuff to the username, the strtolower is working as it is showing correctly in my DB tables. So if I use $this->input->post(); command and display the value what will I get, I will get what I input and not the result after the rules. Looks like all the things doesn't really connect after I read the comments from the other post's contributor.